# Spring Boot - Testing - tearDown for a bean

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, junit5, spring-boot-test

I use @EmbeddedKafka annotation as follows to have a kafka mock:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1,
    topics = {"topic"},
    brokerProperties = {
        "auto.create.topics.enable=${topics.autoCreate:false}",
        "delete.topic.enable=${topic.delete:true}",
        "broker.id=2"})
public class KafkaUsersTest {
    @Autowired
    private EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafka;

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        // test something
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        // test something
    }

    ...
}
```

Now, after The tests finish I'd like to close the embeddedKafka bean. Something like this:

```
    @AfterAll
    public void tearDown(){
        embeddedKafka.getKafkaServers().forEach(KafkaServer::shutdown);
        embeddedKafka.getKafkaServers().forEach(KafkaServer::awaitShutdown);
    }
```

The problem is:

- An @AfterAll method can only be static.
- If I make it static - then also the embeddedKafka has to be static, and then @Autowired annotation will not work.

I guess I can the bean to a static field from one of the tests and then use it in the tearDown(), but it's really ugly.

What is the "good practice" for closing a bean only once after all tests have completed?

Comment: Probably it can help: https://www.concretepage.com/testing/junit-5/junit-5-beforeall-and-afterall-example#Non-Static

Comment: Have you tried using the `@ClassRule` for creating embedded Kafka rather auto-wiring `@Autowired` embeddedKafka?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> An @AfterAll method can only be static.

That's not true.

From the [JUnit 5 User Guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-annotations):

> Denotes that the annotated method should be executed after all @Test, @RepeatedTest, @ParameterizedTest, and @TestFactory methods in the current class; analogous to JUnit 4’s @AfterClass. Such methods are inherited (unless they are hidden or overridden) and must be static (unless the "per-class" test instance lifecycle is used).

An `@AfterAll` method can be non-static if you use `@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)`. This is also documented in the [JUnit 5 User Guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-test-instance-lifecycle):

> The "per-class" mode has some additional benefits over the default "per-method" mode. Specifically, with the "per-class" mode it becomes possible to declare @BeforeAll and @AfterAll on non-static methods as well as on interface default methods.